# SMTP to gmail loop back my domain postfix

Tags: smtp, postfix

I am trying to send gmail my local postfix.

I want to sent from `info@example.com` to `whitebear@gmail.com`

I am using `bear` user to sent email to SMTP.

It looks like sent correctly.

```
[bear@jp1 ~]$ telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 jp1.example.jp ESMTP Postfix
EHLO
501 Syntax: EHLO hostname
EHLO tcpfx.com
250-jp1.muty.jp
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
MAIL FROM: info
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: whitebear@gmail.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
test
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as F224B5C0AC9
```

My `/var/log/maillog` is like this , it returned the mail to somehow `bear@exapmle.com`

```
Dec 19 17:26:02 jp1 postfix/cleanup[29800]: 1ECAE5C0BF0: message-id=<20181219082602.1ECAE5C0BF0@jp1.example.jp>
Dec 19 17:26:02 jp1 postfix/qmgr[29773]: 1ECAE5C0BF0: from=<root@example.com>, size=780, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 19 17:26:02 jp1 postfix/local[29801]: 1ECAE5C0BF0: to=<daichi@example.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.08, delays=0.03/0.05/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Dec 19 17:26:02 jp1 postfix/qmgr[29773]: 1ECAE5C0BF0: removed
Dec 19 17:26:04 jp1 postfix/cleanup[29789]: F224B5C0AC9: message-id=<20181219082600.F224B5C0AC9@jp1.example.jp>
Dec 19 17:26:04 jp1 postfix/qmgr[29773]: F224B5C0AC9: from=<info@example.com>, size=332, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 19 17:26:04 jp1 postfix/smtp[29802]: F224B5C0AC9: to=<whitebear@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[108.177.97.26]:25, delay=13, delays=12/0.01/0.35/0.53, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1545207964 bf4si15251918plb.163 - gsmtp)
Dec 19 17:26:04 jp1 postfix/qmgr[29773]: F224B5C0AC9: removed
Dec 19 17:26:11 jp1 postfix/pickup[29772]: 334AC5C0AC9: uid=0 from=<root>
Dec 19 17:26:11 jp1 postfix/cleanup[29800]: 334AC5C0AC9: message-id=<20181219082611.334AC5C0AC9@jp1.example.jp>
Dec 19 17:26:11 jp1 postfix/qmgr[29773]: 334AC5C0AC9: from=<root@example.com>, size=6920, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 19 17:26:11 jp1 postfix/local[29801]: 334AC5C0AC9: to=<bear@example.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=68, delays=68/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Dec 19 17:26:11 jp1 postfix/qmgr[29773]: 334AC5C0AC9: removed
```

in my main.cf
I have these setting.

```
myhostname = jp1.example.jp
mydomain = example.com
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
```

Is there anywhere I need to check???

`postconf -n`

```
[bear@jp1 ~]$ postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = example.com
myhostname = jp1.example.jp
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,reject_unknown_client,permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks  permit_sasl_authenticated  reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
[daichi@jp1 ~]$
```

Comment: What does the returned message actually say? What is your full postfix configuration (postconf -n)?

Comment: I added the postconf -n . I am not sure how to check email but, `[bear@jp1 ~]$ mail` returns `No mail for bear`